# Why do two unrelated lines of code change GLSL shader colour?

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I've got a GLSL vertex shader that works fine:

```
void main(void){

gl_Position = ftransform();
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

Along with the fragment shader (which is not relevant to this question), they output a textured model, which is what I'd expect.

[image]

However, when I add two unrelated lines of code:

```
void main(void){

gl_Position = ftransform();
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
surfaceNormal = normal; //Sets an out vec3 called surfaceNormal to normal.
toLightVector = lightPosition - position; //Does the same as the above.
}
```

Everything just seems to go black.

[image]

I am unable to find any reason for this. The code does not at all affect the colour that would be outputted by either shader. Indeed, *on their own*, the two lines (to my knowledge) are **absolutely useless** and do **nothing**.

Though not too relevant to the question, here's the fragment shader:

```
in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

uniform vec3 lightColour;

void main(void){
vec4 colour = gl_Color;
vec4 textureColor = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
if(textureColor.a<0.5){
    discard;
}
out_Color = vec4(textureColor.r, textureColor.g, textureColor.b, 1);

}
```

What is going wrong here, and why is my model being turned black?

**UPDATE:** 
    toLightVector = lightPosition - position;
Is actually the line that is the issue. The other line is not relevant to the issue.

Comment: May be something to do with the fact you've declared two vec3 items you haven't used and that are presumably optimised away.  See if it still does that if you put pass_textureCoords as the last statement.

Comment: When OpenGL GLSL compiler see unused variables, it doesn't hesitate to remove it. So maybe your vertex shader pass all the data, but your fragment shader, using only `pass_textureCoords`, remove the others, and then there is a shift problem. Try to "fake" use of your in variables in fragment shader, like `if (surfaceNormal.x == toLightVector.x) colour.r += 0.01;`

Comment: maybe because you are using (deprecated) fixed function pipeline functionality which comes with lighting, I suggest you cull out all deprecated stuff from your code.

Comment: @Robinson I tried putting it last, but the issue stayed the same.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Where am I using the fixed-function pipeline? Shaders overwrite that anyway. I don't understand what it has to do with those two lines of code specifically causing the issue.

Comment: @Joehot200 `ftransform`

Comment: @ratchetfreak Oh, right - That's true. However, it definitely doesn't come with lighting as far as I'm aware. If you've got information to the contrary, that would be great. Also, is there anything you recommend me using *instead* of `fTransform()`?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Also, if `ftransform` is not recommended, what would be the recommended thing to do? I currently don't see any reason to stop using the "fixed-function pipeline", but if there's a good reason then I definitely will.

Comment: @Joehot200 create and manage your own matrices and pass them as uniforms, and use VertexAttribArray and glDrawArrays to pass the position rather than glVertex.

Comment: please provide the full vertex shader (incl variable declarations)

Comment: The shader probably doesn't compile because of those additional lines. As @Bahbar also suggests, it's impossible to tell without seeing the full shader code. As it is posted, it uses undefined variables.